# Zend framework 2: использование нескольких моделей

Tags: php, zend2

Только только начал осваивать *zf2*. Попытался создать две модели. Действовал основываясь на [этих уроках](http://codepress.ru/%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA/zend-framework-2.html). Вот что у меня получилось в папке module\Album\src\Album\Model:

```
Album.php
AlbumTable.php
Photo.php
PhotoTable.php
```

Когда пытаюсь из контроллера получить доступ к модели

```
PhotoTable ($this->getPhotoTable())
```

не выходит, после непродолжительного анализа оказалось, что модель все равно используется `Album`. Где что стоит посмотреть исправить, чтобы использовать этим модели одновременно в одном контроллере?